# How to create a custom profile in SonarQube with the selected rules from PMD, Findbugs and Checkstyle

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I need to create a custom quality profile in SonarQube by selecting only two or three rules from PMD, Findbugs and Checkstyle and to run the analysis.

Note : The default profile contains more than 500 rules and i don't want to include all of them in my analysis. 
I need to create a new profile with selected rules from PMD, Findbugs and Checkstyle.